# XLSX / XLConnect set cell style to be numeric

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlconnect

I want to format my excel output to be numeric. But based on other part of my code, I can only change the format through write-as-excel step. I looked into R documentations such as XLSX and XLConnect packages, and seems `cellStyle`  and `DataFormat` will be two things to use. But I'm struggling with the `cs <- CellStyle()` part. It doesn't work at all :(

I provide a really basic excel worksheet below, and hope if anyone could help me out. I would be really appreciated!

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 column

setCellValue(cells[[1, 1]], "1.29")

cs <- CellStyle(wb, dataFormat=DataFormat("0.00"))
setCellStyle(cells, cs)

saveWorkbook(wb, "foo.xlsx")
shell.exec("foo.xlsx")
```

The resulting excel cell is posted below with an warning msg "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

[image]

Comment: For me, your code generates this error `Error in .jcall (cell, "V", "setCellStyle", cellStyle$ref) :   RcallMethod: invalid object parameter`. If it's necessary to convert via setCellStyle, you would need to follow the directions in DataFormat regarding discovering the correct format in Excel.
Or you can change `setCellValue(cells[[1, 1]], "1.29")` to `setCellValue(cells[[1, 1]], as.numeric("1.29"))` as @pnuts suggested.

Comment: @K.Daisey Ahhh! thanks soooo much!!!!!